# How do I fix System.IO.IOException from SerialPort.Write in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a virtual COM device (USB to UART) that I am attempting to command using C# SerialPort. When I call the Write or WriteLine methods I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception (System.IO.IOException): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Int32 timeout)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write(String text)
```

I've confirmed port, baud rate, parity, and handshake with both the device documentation and by successfully communicating through PuTTY, so the issue must be with my C# code.

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort(commId, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
{
    Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff,
    ReadTimeout = 5000,
    WriteTimeout = 5000,
    NewLine = "\r", //added during debug
    DtrEnable = true, //added during debug
    RtsEnable = true //added during debug
};

_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort_DataReceived);

_serialPort.Open();

_serialPort.DiscardInBuffer(); //added during debug
_serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer(); //added during debug
_serialPort.Write("echo");
_serialPort.WriteLine("echo");
```

Comment: looks like a baudrate problem.

Comment: try setting it to `1` to start with

Comment: this might help discover the problem: https://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/

Comment: @JohnB you are correct, dropping the baudrate to 1 fixed the problem. Any idea why SerialPort and PuTTY would behave differently? Got this baudrate straight from the manufacturer.